# How to ask for permission to access location every time a view is opened, if the user hasn't approved location

Tags: ios, swift, location-services

I am trying to open a view controller that requires access to a users location. Currently i have the below code running. This, however, only asks the user for permission the first time they open the view. After that, if the user denied, the app crashes.

I have this function run at the beginning of my viewDidLoad() and then I run

```
centerMapOnLocation(CLLocationManager().location!, mapView: mapView)
```

this line of code is where it crashes with the error message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What is causing this?

```
func askForPermission() {
    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == true {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Service Error", message: "Go to settings to approve Location services", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create OK button
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)

        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        // Create Cancel button
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present Dialog message
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

I have also tried to run the following function and was met with a crash at the same location.

```
func checkAuthorizationStatus() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        break
    case .denied:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Service Error", message: "Go to settings to approve Location services", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create OK button
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)

        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        // Create Cancel button
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present Dialog message
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        break
    case .restricted:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Service Error", message: "Go to settings to approve Location services", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create OK button
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)

        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        // Create Cancel button
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present Dialog message
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
        break
    case .authorizedAlways: break
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't. Once the user denies, they need to go to Settings and update the permission. Your app can't do anything except offer to launch the Settings app page for your app.

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do. I am trying to prompt a UIAlert that asks the user to turn on locations. If they select "ok" i want to open settings, but if they select "cancel" i want to dismiss the view controller they opened  @rmaddy

Comment: Update your question with details about your crash. What's the error? What line is causing the crash?

Comment: I just updated @rmaddy

Comment: Don't force-unwrap optionals.

Comment: That doesn't prevent the function from running, though. How can I still run the function? Force unwrapping wouldn't produce an error if a location would be provided, and if a location isn't provided, the view should dismiss anyway @rmaddy

Comment: `I have this function run at the beginning of my viewDidLoad() and then I run` . This sums up your crash. This line of code is executed anyway. It should only be executed if user has already granted location access.

Comment: but the UIAlert never shows and therefore the view can never be dismissed. That's where the problem lies @SoroushShahi

Comment: I updated the question with another function i tried that didnt work

Comment: @rmaddy how would I not force-unwrap that optional?

Comment: There are countless tutorials regarding Swift and properly handling optionals. But note that `CLLocationManager().location` will never be useful because you can't get an immediate location from a freshly created location manager. That attempt is simply wrong.

Comment: update your question with the `viewDidLoad ` function.